# How to create a Vue method that dynamically chooses an icon from a list for a corresponding extension?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to display a proper icon depending on what type of file it is.

I have this `div` that displays either:

- an image
- or a `<v-icon>` component (where `{{ext.value}}` is the icon name to display)

#### div

```
<div>
  <img v-if="isImg(props.item.path)" :src="props.item.path">
  <v-icon v-else v-for="ext in extensionsList" :key="ext.id">
    {{ext.value}}   <=== should put a corresponding value if matches any extension
  </v-icon>
</div>
```

#### data

```
data () {
  return {
    extensionsList: [
      {value: "generic_icon", extension: ['.ini', '.dll']},
      {value: "code_icon", extension: ['.json', '.py']},
      {value: "text_icon", extension: '.txt'}
    ]
  }
}
```

I can get a file extension by using this method:

```
getExtension (value) {
  return path.extname(value)
}
```

`props.item` is an object containing file properties so I pass that as the input  into `path.extname()` and it returns something like:  `'.ini'`, or `'.jpg'`

---

- How do I make this work? I don't know how to call a method when `v-else` branch is true, do I use a method, a computed property?
- And how to make sure it uses a generic file icon `value: "generic_icon"` (the `[0]` in the `extensionsList`) for all extensions that do not match any item in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just make a method to return the associated icon:

```
methods: {
  getIcon(ext) {
    let icon = this.extensionsList.find((item) => {
      let { extension } = item;
      if (Array.isArray(extension)) {
        return extension.includes(ext);
      } else if (typeof extension === 'string') {
        return extension === ext;
      }
    }) || {};

    return icon.value || "generic_icon";
  }
}
```

And then call that in the template like so:

```
<div>
  <img v-if="isImg(props.item.path)" :src="props.item.path">
  <v-icon v-else>
    {{ getIcon(getExtension(props.item.path)) }}
  </v-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not sure how to make it work though, `getIcon()` executes several times because this div is inside an iterator that displays several objects.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You'll need to include that context in your post.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine, thank you very much for that. It's just 
 the div is inside a component that updates multiple times and so by executing the `{{ getIcon(getExtension(props.item.path)) }}` method right in the template like that triggers this method multiple times as well. I won't be able to post all the code here, but your method works and solves the problem, I'm gonna accept that as the best answer, thank you

Comment: I noticed that both `foo.js` and `foo.json` are receiving the same icon, the one that specified for json: `{value: "code_icon", extension: '.json'}`. So I'm guessing it doesn't match the string exactly. Is there a way to make sure it matches the whole string so that `foo.js` would use its own icon?

Comment: Ah, ok that's because `'.json'.includes('.js')` is `true`. It would be simplest to change your `extensionsList` structure so that the `extension` property is always an array (i.e. `extension: ['.json']`). That way you could just find the item in the list via `item.extension.includes`. But, I'll update my answer to work for your current structure.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for updating the code, you're awesome! It didn't occur to me that I can just use arrays for every item to make it work, but your current solution works for mixed structure arrays now as well, that's good